# No savechages diz que coluna está null e tem valor

Tags: c#, wpf

Quando eu chamo o meu método para gravar, o objeto vem todo preenchido, mas quando o savechanges() é chamado diz que o IdBalanca é null e no entanto ele tem o valor de 1.
Método Inserir:

```
public virtual void Inserir(T item) 
        {
            contexto.Set<T>().Add(item);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

O objeto Item vem todo preenchido. Veja abaixo uma imagem em cima do objeto antes de gravar(savechanges)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A única forma que eu consegui, foi criar um campo identity. Sem ele, não consegui nada.

Comment: Você quer explicitamente passar o valor do IdBalanca ao invés de deixar o banco gerar com auto-increment?

Comment: @Alisson, sim, porque assim está no cliente, mas vamos dar um jeito e acho que o entity consegue isso, não? Porque senão o entity é falho nesse sentido, de trabalhar com campos não gerados automaticamente

Answer (score 1):

O **Entity Framework** por padrão trata as chaves primárias como `Identity`, portanto ele irá ignorar qualquer valor que você definir para `IdBalanca`, uma vez que ela seja a chave. Ao mesmo tempo, por ser Identity, o Entity Framework *acredita* que sua tabela terá um valor gerado automaticamente (ex: auto-increment).

Por isso dá esse erro, ele ignora o que foi preenchido no código, e não define um valor ao inserir no tabela, mas como a tabela ao mesmo tempo não é `Identity`, ocorre esse erro.

Para dizer ao **Entity Framework** que o valor não é gerado pelo banco, mas sim pela própria aplicação, você precisa configurar o campo com o atributo `DatabaseGenerated`:

```
public class Balanca
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int IdBalanca { get; set; }

    // demais campos...

}
```

Comment: Valeu. Vou testar e ver se deu certo.